# Flutter: about overflow behavior when hiragana and alphabet are mixed in the string of the text widget

Tags: flutter

I'm not particularly troubled by this problem right now, but I don't know the reason for the phenomenon I happened to find, so let me ask you a question.

When the code below is executed on iPhoneSE2, if the second argument of the substring method is 56, only "ああああいいい" will be displayed,
and if the second argument is set to 57, the following alphabet will also be displayed.

I have no idea why. If anyone knows anything, please let me know.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String str1 = 'ああああいいいaaa,aaaaaaaaaa,aaaaabbbbb,bbbbbbbbbc,cccccccccc,wwwwwwwwww,mmmmmmmmmm,';
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          //width: 500,
          child:Text(
            str1.substring(0,56),//←here!
            maxLines: 1,
            //overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```